# Replace/anonymize value in list of dict in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to replace the value of the key `extension_last_heartbeat_time` (date) with a static string `<LAST_HEARTBEAT_TIME>` in this list of dicts

```yaml
[
        {
            "vcenter": "vcenter-A",
            "vcenter_extension_info": [
                {
                    "extension_company": "VMware Inc.",
                    "extension_key": "com.vmware.vim.sms",
                    "extension_label": "VMware vCenter Storage Monitoring Service",
                    "extension_last_heartbeat_time": "2020-11-03T09:05:41.676497+00:00",
                    "extension_type": "",
                    "extension_version": "5.5"
                },
                {
                    "extension_company": "VMware Inc.",
                    "extension_key": "com.vmware.vim.vsm",
                    "extension_last_heartbeat_time": "2020-11-03T09:05:41.678007+00:00",
                    "extension_type": "",
                    "extension_version": "6.5"
                },
                {
                    "extension_company": null,
                    "extension_key": "VirtualCenter",
                    "extension_last_heartbeat_time": "2020-11-03T09:05:41.684018+00:00",
                    "extension_type": "",
                    "extension_version": "1.0"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "vcenter": "vcenter-B",
            "vcenter_extension_info": [
                {
                    "extension_company": "VMware Inc.",
                    "extension_key": "com.vmware.vim.sms",
                    "extension_last_heartbeat_time": "2020-08-17T13:12:10.529370+00:00",
                    "extension_type": "",
                    "extension_version": "5.5"
                },
                {
                    "extension_company": "VMware Inc.",
                    "extension_key": "com.vmware.vim.vsm",
                    "extension_last_heartbeat_time": "2020-08-17T13:12:10.530946+00:00",
                    "extension_type": "",
                    "extension_version": "6.5"
                },
                {
                    "extension_company": null,
                    "extension_key": "VirtualCenter",
                    "extension_last_heartbeat_time": "2020-08-17T13:12:10.537281+00:00",
                    "extension_version": "1.0"
                }
            ]
        }
]
```

I tried :

```yaml
- name: anonymize last heartbeat time
    set_fact:
      dict: "{{ dict | map('regex_replace', '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.*', '<LAST_HEARTBEAT_TIME>') | list }}"
```

But it removes a big part of the data ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jinja2 data structures are "live", so they are subject to mutation in all jinja2 evaluation contexts. The trick is that (at least as of this post) the `set` statement creates new *local* variables, and does not assign the way a user might expect, leading to some silliness. That's why one must use `dict.update` as a "overwrite this dict member" work-around

```yaml
- set_fact:
    # you didn't say what variable contained that outermost `list[dict]`
    # so change that as needed
    vcenter_data: |
        {%- for i in vcenter_data -%}
        {%-   for e in i.vcenter_extension_info -%}
        {%-     set _ = e.update({
            "extension_last_heartbeat_time": new_extension_last_heartbeat_time}) -%}
        {%-   endfor -%}
        {%- endfor -%}
        {{ vcenter_data }}
  vars:
    new_extension_last_heartbeat_time: '1111-22-33'
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways of resolving this is by using regex_replace.
If the data is in the variable "vcenter_data" then the solution could look like this :

```
    - name: anonymize instance uuid
      set_fact:
        vcenter_data: "{{ vcenter_data| regex_replace('[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}', '<INSTANCE_UUID>') }}"
```