# merge dictionaries based on regex

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I would like to merge a dictionary into the results of device1.something.org, based on the item.name using regex.

```
  vars:
    gig:  
      type: "1000BASE-T (1GE)"
    virtual:
      type: "Virtual"
    - name: SETTING INT TYPE 1GE
      set_fact:
        interfacetype: "{{ interfacetype | default([]) | combine(gig) }}"
      loop: "{{ansible_network_resources.interfaces}}"
      when: item.name | regex_search('(ge-)')
    - name: SETTING INT TYPE VIRTUAL
      set_fact:
        interfacetype: "{{ interfacetype | default([]) | combine(virtual) }}"
      loop: "{{ansible_network_resources.interfaces}}"
      when: item.name == "irb" or 
            item.name == "lo0"
```

what I get from ansible facts is below, using the juniper collections junipernetworks.junos.junos_facts

```
    ok: [device1.something.org] => {
"ansible_network_resources.interfaces": [
    {
        "enabled": true,
        "mtu": 9216,
        "name": "ge-0/0/0"
    },
    {
        "enabled": false,
        "mtu": 9216,
        "name": "ge-0/0/1"
    },
    {
        "enabled": false,
        "mtu": 9216,
        "name": "ge-0/0/2"
    },
    {
        "enabled": false,
        "mtu": 9216,
        "name": "ge-0/0/3"
    },
    {
        "enabled": false,
        "mtu": 9216,
        "name": "ge-0/0/4"
    },
    {
        "description": "agaga2",
        "enabled": true,
        "mtu": 9216,
        "name": "et-0/1/0"
    },
    {
        "enabled": false,
        "mtu": 9216,
        "name": "et-0/1/1"
    },
    {
        "enabled": true,
        "mtu": 9216,
        "name": "xe-0/2/0"
    },
    {
        "enabled": false,
        "mtu": 9216,
        "name": "xe-0/2/1"
    },
    {
        "enabled": false,
        "mtu": 9216,
        "name": "xe-0/2/2"
    },
    {
        "description": "blabla1",
        "enabled": true,
        "mtu": 9216,
        "name": "xe-0/2/3"
    },
    {
        "enabled": true,
        "name": "irb"
    },
    {
        "enabled": true,
        "name": "lo0"
    }
]
```

I would like to get something like this, where based on the item.name I can create another list of dictionary but with the item.type in this case.

```
"ansible_network_resources.interfaces": [
    {
        type: "1000BASE-T (1GE)"
        "enabled": true,
        "mtu": 9216,
        "name": "ge-0/0/0"
    },
    {
        type: "1000BASE-T (1GE)"
        "enabled": false,
        "mtu": 9216,
        "name": "ge-0/0/1"
    },
    {
        type: "1000BASE-T (1GE)"
        "enabled": false,
        "mtu": 9216,
        "name": "ge-0/0/2"
    },
    {
        type: "1000BASE-T (1GE)"            
        "enabled": false,
        "mtu": 9216,
        "name": "ge-0/0/3"
    },
    {
        type: "1000BASE-T (1GE)"
        "enabled": false,
        "mtu": 9216,
        "name": "ge-0/0/4"
    },
    {
        "description": "agaga2",
        "enabled": true,
        "mtu": 9216,
        "name": "et-0/1/0"
    },
    {
        type: "Virtual"
        "enabled": true,
        "name": "irb"
    },
    {
        type: "Virtual"
        "enabled": true,
        "name": "lo0"
    }
```

Comment: While not a line-for-line answer to your question, [my answer from earlier about patching embedded `dict`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65953988/replace-value-in-list-of-dict-in-ansible/65958617#65958617) is relevant

Comment: Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/225016/mdaniel for taking the time to answer this.
I will take a look and see if I can resolve my issue with that.